# Slider code in email - Want it to work for Gmail

Tags: html, css

I have asked questions regarding this code before. It is working fine. The only issue is that I would like to use it so the it works in the Gmail web client. It seems to work on Gmail mobile but not desktop and normal online HTML works. I know email clients limit CSS functionality but any help in getting functionality like this working would be great.

WORKING SNIPPET:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
 display:flex;
 width:600px;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.slider-holder {
  order:-1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 3000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 280px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 7000s; /*Use a big value to block the image change*/
  left: 0;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a[href="#slider-image-0"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: 0.5px; /*Yes it's not 0px here, we need something different from the initial state to be able to trigger the transition (Yes I know it's not intuitive ..)*/
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-1"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -600px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-2"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1200px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-3"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -1800px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

a[href="#slider-image-4"]:hover~.slider-holder .image-holder {
  left: -2400px;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.button-holder>a>img {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#slider-image-0"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70" alt="" width="70" style="border-width:0 !important;outline-style:none !important;"></a>
<div class="slider-holder">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/ff0000" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/00ff00" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/f0f0f0" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280/0000ff" class="slider-image" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x280" class="slider-image" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use the css inline, directly on the element via the *style* property. Also note that some E-mail clients will prompt the user for whether they'd like the images to be displayed or not. Also, just because you tagged html5 and css3, refrain from using those notations when it comes to E-mails. Use regular html and css. html5 and css3 is not widely supported among E-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table layout, inline css and avoid using images as replace of content. Here is great guide: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of CSS supported by email clients [link](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/).
Try to add you CSS classes in head section of HTML.